# Why string variable in JSON does not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have got the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var adress = [];
  var locations = ' [';
  $('.office p').each(function(el) {
    adress[el] = $(this).text();
    locations = locations + '{address:\''+adress[el]+'\', data: \'0\', options:{icon: "http://selectner.com/img/bullet.png"}},';
  });

  locations = locations + ']';
        console.log(locations);


     $('#tablink').click(function (e) {

     $('#map').gmap3({
      map:{
         options:{
           center:[51.4675954,0.048876],
           zoom: 2,
           scrollwheel: true,
          draggable: true, 
          }
      },
     marker:{
         values : locations,
         options:{
          draggable: true
        },
        events:{
                    }
    }
   });
  });
});
```

If I will copy console.log results and paste it into JSON (in gmap3 function - locations place) - all will work, but now it is not working.

I think, that I must to use JSON.parse(), but it write error to me:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 1 column 3 of the JSON data

How I can solve this problem?

Comment: Paste the log output here.

Comment: That's not valid JSON even.

Comment: Stop trying to cobble together JSON yourself – create proper data structures out of arrays/objects, and then have those encoded as JSON when needed using the browser’s native methods (or a framework/polyfill if necessary).

Comment: @LShetty: I rebuild with double squares, but it still don't work. Now code console.log is `[{"address":'Toronto, SCARBOROUGH JUNCTIO', "data": '0', "options":{"icon": 'http://selectner.com/img/bullet.png'}},{"address":'Moscow, tverskaya street, 18', "data": '0', "options":{"icon": 'http://selectner.com/img/bullet.png'}},{"address":'Leipzig, SÜDVORSTADT', "data": '0', "options":{"icon": 'http://selectner.com/img/bullet.png'}},]`

Comment: You still have invalid JSON over there. That's why it doesn't work. Maybe you can try simply using a JSON serializer instead of concatenating those strings.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov how I can create valid json and check it?

Comment: @butteff, did you read my answer below? It kinda shows how to do that. The idea is that you manipulate javascript objects, arrays in your case. And once you are ready you simply use the `JSON.stringify`method to serialize this javascript to a valid JSON object. You just forget about using the `+` operator.

Comment: http://jsonlint.com/ write, that problems in "," in adress line, but how I can take adress without ","? I need to have it

Comment: it is works: `locations = '[{"address":"Toronto, SCARBOROUGH JUNCTIO", "data": "0", "options":{"icon": "http://selectner.com/img/bullet.png"}},{"address":"Moscow, tverskaya street, 18", "data": "0", "options":{"icon": "http://selectner.com/img/bullet.png"}},{"address":"Leipzig, SÜDVORSTADT", "data": "0", "options":{"icon": "http://selectner.com/img/bullet.png"}}]';
    var jslocations = JSON.parse(locations);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't build JSON using string concatenation operations. **Just don't**. **Never, ever**.

You may try using a simple [`JSON serializer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) which is designed for this purpose so that you never get invalid JSON:

```
var addresses = [];
$('.office p').each(function() {
    addresses.push({
        address: $(this).text(),
        data: 0,
        options: {
            icon: 'http://selectner.com/img/bullet.png'
        }
    });
});

var locations = JSON.stringify(addresses);
console.log(locations);
// At this stage it is guaranteed that the addresses variable will
// contain valid JSON string
```

Comment: I agree with you, but OP is using a plugin and this is how the documentation says how to do it :/

Comment: Oh that's really weird. Could you point to this documentation? Maybe the authors of it should be notified about the mistake they did. I mean if a documentation is showing an example where JSON is being built with string  concatenation operations, then, well, OMG.

Comment: I am not sure where in this example a JSON is being built using string concatenations. They seem to be building some DOM elements using string concatenations (which is also bad) but not JSON.

Comment: The OP's problem is that he is building JSON using string concatenation operations. Chances of getting this right are close to 0.

Comment: Yep I see now, sorry about the confusion. Well also trying to build your own JSON, we all have been there :)

Answer (score 0):

That's because your "string" isn't valid JSON. Read more about the structure of JSON here: http://json.org/

Also, you're already in JavaScript, why are you building JSON when you can already use objects?